# bankid: how to download one's bankid client certificate at SEB?

Tags: bankid

I look for a 100% Linux solution to use Sweden's BankId.

There is information online:

- https://github.com/virtualforce/bankid-authentication/
- http://www.herlitz.nu/2017/09/13/integrating-with-swedish-bankid-and-.net/

Now I need to download my client certificate from the bank seb.se

How to download one's client certificate at SEB?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want.

Do you want a Linux BankID client? That's not supported by BankID. You can find out their client requirements here:
https://support.bankid.com/sv/felavhjalpning/systemkrav

Do you want a server solution for using BankID RP interface? Go ahead, the SOAP interface is well documented here:
https://www.bankid.com/rp/info

As for downloading the certificate from SEB, you need to be a bank customer with a Swedish personal number. I'm not a customer, but judging from their website, it seems they only issue [BankID on card](https://seb.se/privat/digitala-tjanster/bankid-pa-kort) and [Mobile BankID](https://seb.se/privat/digitala-tjanster/mobilt-bankid). Once you're logged into the Internet bank with your Digipass you should have no problem to find out how to issue a mobile BankID.

BankID on card might take some more effort though.

BankID does have a [demo system for development purposes](https://demo.bankid.com). There you can issue a fake BankID to use in the development mode, "test".